# Gmaps in a fragment Api 2 Android app

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm developing an app with a fragment that contains a map (from google not Openstreet). But I'm at really beginning and I have a problem in the xml of the fragment. Eclipse return me this error:

> Fatal error: main Caused by: android.view.InflateException:Binary XML
>   file line #4: Error inflating class
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

Below I paste the fragment_geolocalizzazione.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#00000000" >

</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

I inflate this layout but it returns error on this (`com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`) and it return null when the main activity call it.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551) will be helpful.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try, today I haven't time anymore :/ I'll reply to you here :) Thank you so much !! @Fllo

Comment: @Fllo maybe your code works but now I have other problems that make the app crash :( this is making me crazy :/

Comment: You should edit your question and post the logcat where you have the error. It will help us to figure it out what is wrong in your code.